# Migrate Files to another server with ACL permissions

Tags: linux, unix, acl

I am porting my directory system from Solaris to Linux box.
I have a lot of files with ACL's[File Access Control] set on them. I thought of making a tar and copying it over to the new box. Will the tar can copy the ACL permissions as well?
Will links[ soft and Hard ] will also get copied in tar file??

Answer (score 2):

Links, both hard and symbolic, have not been a problem on Linux for quite some time; [`GNU tar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/)  handles them just fine. I believe that Solaris `tar` also works fine - if I remember correctly it even has an option for warning the user if the number of hard links that is has detected for an inode is not equal to its link count.

ACLs, on the other hand, are a different story. `GNU tar` neither archives nor restores ACLs and extended attributes and I do not know if the `tar` implementation in Solaris is any better.

You would be better off using [`star`](http://freecode.com/projects/star), which supports pretty much everything that you may need...